# My solr suggestions doesn't display results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I updated my solr to 4.9.1 (I want to implement solr `Suggester`) and updated its `solrconfig.xml`

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">cat</str>
    <str name="weightField">price</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

And here is my `sunspot.yml`

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development
```

But when accessing `http://localhost:8982/solr/development/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=ac` There is no result value :

```
{"responseHeader": {
     "status":0,"QTime":38
   },
   "command":"build",
   "suggest":{
     "mySuggester": {
        "ac":{
          "numFound":0,
          "suggestions":[]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something important?

I followed [the documentation for the Solr Suggester component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester#Suggester-AddingtheSuggestSearchComponent).

How can I display the suggestions result for my solr?

Thank you :)

Comment: is it stand-alone setup or CloudSolr? What data you have indexed? Did you try longer queries? Try with `term` which you know, that it exist for sure.

Comment: @Ardian I have the same problem. Were you able to figure out a solution

Comment: Hi @TonyVincent, we moved to Elasticsearch :)